# What is the correct way to import an S3 method without importing the whole package

Tags: r, roxygen2

I would like to use one function from a package called `myPackage` called `as.data.frame.mywhateverS3class`

When I look at the package NAMESPACE it looks as follows: `S3method(as.data.frame, mywhateverS3class)`
I would like to use this function inside another package. What I would normally do is specify this in `roxygen2` as @import myPackage such that this generates `import(myPackage)` inside the other package. That works.

But in this case I would like **not to import the whole package but only the S3 method**. 
When I specify `importFrom(myPackage, as.data.frame)`, or `importFrom(myPackage, as.data.frame.mywhateverS3class)` this fails as as.data.frame is not exported in `myPackage` and as.data.frame.mywhateverS3class is hidden when I type `methods(as.data.frame)`

Do I really need to import the whole package NAMESPACE for this? I'm looking at http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html and can't seem to find how to restrict the import to just the S3method without importing the whole NAMESPACE. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This might be tricky, as the S3 method might depend on other functions in the package...

Comment: In the question and in my case, the generic is defined in the base package so that is not an issue.

Comment: What happens if you import the package description, but don't actually import anything from it? I think that might be enough to import the S3 method table from the other package.

Comment: When I specify myPackage in the Imports in the DESCRIPTION without putting it in the NAMESPACE, I'm getting at R CMD check the following NOTE: `Namespace in Imports field not imported from: 'myPackage'
All declared Imports should be used.`

Comment: Then import just one function, any function, and the S3 method table will be available automatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59667634/6788081