# How directly access S3 method in roxygen2 R package

Tags: r, roxygen2, r-package

I'm writing my first package with **roxygen2**. The package implements a faster version of `pcdtest()` from **plm** package. Thus I call within my package:

```
merr <- resid(mod)
```

Package plm implements a S3 method for resid. It exports it in **plm**'s NAMESPACE this way:

```
S3method("residuals", "panelmodel")
S3method("residuals", "plm")
```

To be able to use `resid()`, I import whole **plm** package via

```
#' @import plm
```

Is there any way to access the proper method directly via `::`? Or to import  just the method? Or other nicer workaround?

Many thanks,
Michal

Comment: Possibly `importFrom(plm, some_method.some_class)` in your `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: That's what I expected but I wasn't able to make it work. Function `residuals.panelmodel()` is not exported -- it is exported as S3method. How can I access it? (Actually, I would prefer accessing it directly, even without importFrom directive. Still, importing one function is perhaps better than importing a whole package.)

Answer (score 1):

Late, but... Packages don't need to be attached for their registered S3 methods to be available, they just need to be loaded. Therefore, you don't need necessarily to `import(plm)` (which loads and attaches the package), but just to `importFrom(plm, somefunction)` (which loads the package, but attaches just this function), any function or symbol declared as `export(somefunction)` in `plm`'s NAMESPACE.

Comment: This solution feels quite unsatisfactory: why am I importing `somefunction` if I am not using that function? Whenever I need to comment code to explain that, “no, actually, this code serves a purpose even though it looks useless” (and this is definitely the case here!), I'd rather there was a better solution.

Comment: You don't need to import anything, you just need to make sure the package is loaded.  `loadNamespace("plm")` does that without affecting the namespace other than adding its methods.