# How to declare a dependency on an R package from which you only use S3/S4 methods, but no exports?

Tags: r

Currently I have in my package `DESCRIPTION`, a dependency on `dbplyr`:

```
Imports:
    dbplyr,
    dplyr
```

`dbplyr` is useful almost solely because of the S3 methods it defines: https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/main/NAMESPACE. The actual functions you call to use `dbplyr` are almost entirely from `dplyr`.

By putting `dbplyr` in my Imports, it should automatically get loaded, but not attached, which should be enough to register its S3 methods: https://r-pkgs.org/dependencies-mindset-background.html#sec-dependencies-attach-vs-load.

This seems to work fine, but whenever I `R CMD check`, it tells me:

```
N  checking dependencies in R code (10.8s)
   Namespace in Imports field not imported from: ‘dbplyr’
     All declared Imports should be used.
```

Firstly, why does `R CMD check` even check this, considering that it often makes sense to load packages without importing them. Secondly, how am I supposed to satisfy `R CMD check` without loading things into my namespace that I don't want or need?

Comment: This is one (of many!) bugs in `R CMD check`, and the chance of it getting fixed is unfortunately rather slim. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59667634/1968

Comment: @KonradRudolph, your complaint is unfair. When a patch was submitted to fix a slightly different bug related to this one, it was accepted and merged within a day.  This one is harder, since nothing in the package code makes it obvious that `dbplyr` is being used.  The check code can't see something that isn't there.

Comment: @user2554330 I don’t agree that it’s unfair. The ‘codetools’ repository (which is at the basis of this) has critical issues and a merge request that are *several years old* and have no response. I am actually surprised that there is any recent activity on this repository *at all*, but it's only a cosmetic change. The last actual development happened over two years ago, and the last serious development mostly happened a decade ago.

Comment: No, this isn't `codetools`.  It's the `tools` package that implements this.  I think sometimes it calls `codetools`, but not in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure two of your assumptions are false.

First, putting `Imports: dbplyr` into your `DESCRIPTION` file won't load it, so its methods won't be loaded from that alone.  Basically the `Imports` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file just guarantees that `dbplyr` is available to be loaded when requested.  If you import something via the `NAMESPACE` file, that will cause it to be loaded.  If you evaluate `dbplyr::something` that will cause it to be loaded.  Executing `loadNamespace("dbplyr")` is another way, and there are a few others. You may also load some other package that loads it.

Second, I think you have misinterpreted the error message.  It isn't saying that you loaded it without importing it (though it would complain about that too), it is saying that it can't detect any use of it in your package, so maybe it shouldn't be a requirement for installing your package.

Unfortunately, the code to detect uses is fallible, so it sometimes misses uses.  Examples I've heard about are:

- if the package is only used in the default value for a function argument.  This has been fixed in R-devel.
- if the package is only used during the build to construct some object, e.g. code like `someclass <- R6::R6Class( ... )` needs `R6`, but the check code won't see it because it looks at `someclass`, not at the source code that created it.
- if the use of the package is hidden by specifying the name of the package in a character variable.
- if the need for the package is indirect, e.g. you need to use `ggplot2::geom_hex`.  That needs the `hexbin` package, but `ggplot2` only declares it as "Suggested".

These examples come from this discussion:  https://github.com/hadley/r-pkgs/issues/828#issuecomment-1421353457 .

The recommended workaround there is to create an object that refers to the imported package explicitly, e.g. putting the line

```
dummy_r6 <- function() R6::R6Class
```

into your package is enough to suppress the note without actually loading `R6`.  (It will be loaded if you ever call this function.)

However, your requirement is stronger:  you do need to make sure `dbplyr` is loaded if you want its methods to be used.  I'd put something in your `.onLoad()` function that triggers the load.  For example,

```
.onLoad <- function(lib, pkg) {
  # Make sure the dbplyr methods are loaded
  loadNamespace("dbplyr")
}
```

EDITED TO ADD:  As pointed out in the comments, there's a bug in the check code that means it won't detect this as being a use of `dbplyr`.  You really need to do both things, e.g.

```
.onLoad <- function(lib, pkg) {
  # Make sure the dbplyr methods are loaded
  loadNamespace("dbplyr")
  # Work around bug in code checking in R 4.2.2 for use of packages
  dummy <- function() dbplyr::across_apply_fns
}
```

The function used in the dummy construction is arbitrary; it probably doesn't even need to exist, but I chose one that does.

Comment: The issue with just calling `loadNamespace` is that it does not make the spurious `R CMD check` note go away.

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  that sounds like a bug.  The code to check for usage tries to handle this, but I guess something went wrong.  Why not report it?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug but I don't think there is even an attempt to handle this case. And the reason I have not bothered reporting it is because this issue is well known to the core R developers (see the SO answer I linked), and because the maintainer of ‘codetools’ seems to have no interest in the project any more, and none of the several critical issue reports (some years old) have received any response. Discussions on the R developer mailing list also led nowhere.

Comment: You aren't seeing the attempt because you are looking in the wrong place.  Here's where it should be handled:  https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/e0cb77e92fbed832e95b1c33078de8c10b4697e8/src/library/tools/R/QC.R#L5759 .

Comment: Thanks @user2554330, I think you have identified one misconception of mine. The issue about how to formally load a package without attaching it, but also keeping `R CMD check` happy seems to still be a bit unknown. However the workaround you have offered works for the time being.

Comment: Interesting! To be fair that makes it even weirder that this wasn't already fixed (as mentioned, the core R developers are well aware of this behaviour). Feel free to report the bug though. I don't have my Bugzilla credentials on my work computer and I barely use the computer at home at the moment, so I won't get a chance to report it for several days.

Comment: Yes, there's a bug in the check code here:  https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/e0cb77e92fbed832e95b1c33078de8c10b4697e8/src/library/tools/R/QC.R#L5785-L5798 .  That code does the check that packages being loaded are mentioned in `DESCRIPTION`, but it doesn't add the package being loaded to the list of things being used by the package.  A one line fix should be sufficient.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: the core developers are people, and they're busy.  If you make it easy for them to fix things they usually will.  If it's hard, it may end up too far down on the to-do list to ever get done.

Comment: @Migwell, the edited answer should solve both problems.

Comment: If no one else has, I'm happy to report this on Bugzilla? It would be nice to get it fixed.

Comment: @user2554330 I'm an overworked OSS developer myself, I know how it works. I'm just explaining why there's no real incentive to report the bug. Now that you've identified the exact source and, as you say, the candidate fix is a single line of code (`all_imports <<- c(all_imports, pkg)` either at the beginning or the end of the `if(!dunno)` block), please do report the bug with the fix.

Comment: It's now there:  https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18466 .

Comment: Thanks for submitting! I discovered I couldn't because I'm not already a member.