# Best practice for use of Patchwork and ggplot2 library inside a package

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-package, patchwork

What is the best practice when including ggplot2 and patchwork in a function that is part of a custom library? Usually I wouldn't load a complete library but only the required function, e.g.
MLmetrics::RMSE(). But for ggplot I have a lot of ggplot functions, maybe around 10+ per plot.
Of course it's not an impossible task to add a ggplot2:: in front of all of those, I was just wondering what is generally considered the best practice here.
As for the patchwork library this is a bit different because I don't know how to call the specific plot assembly function. My code would look like this:

```
library(patchwork)
assembled_plot <- plot1/plot2/plot3
```

I think this doesn't work:

```
assembled_plot <- patchwork::plot1/plot2/plot3
```

Comment: Try using `patchwork::wrap_plots(plot1, plot2, plot3, ncol = 1)`. See documentation for formatting plot layout.

Comment: I agree, and I suspect that using `+` and `/` are great for convenience during interactive development, but `wrap_plots` would be the more programmatic way when you want to reduce how much you load from other namespaces.

Comment: I think having `loadNamespace("plm")` anywhere in a script (maybe in zzz.R or where you define your imports) should be enough to "activate" `/.ggplot`. You can also use `withr::with_package()` or `withr::local_package()` expose the package's exported functions locally.

Comment: @moodymudskipper None of that is necessary or recommended/idiomatic. Just import the operators using `importFrom` `NAMESPACE` declarations, or use the equivalent Roxygen directive (I’m a bit confused by your comment since I’m fairly sure you know this … brain fart? Or am missing something?).

Comment: You can run `import::from(patchwork, plot_layout)` to make the `/` operator available. More here: https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/226

Comment: @KonradRudolph the operator `/` is in {base}, the method `/.ggplot` is in {patchwork} but is not an exported function, so you cannot use importFrom. Unless you can use importFrom on unexported objects, tbh I've never tried but that would surprise me.

Comment: @moodymudskipper Ah of course “just import the operators” was wrong because S3 doesn’t work this way — you’d need to import *another* (exported) name [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59667634/1968). But yes, that solution stinks, and using `loadNamespace` in this context is probably better. Or we fix R. But I already tried pointing out issues with S3 in R, unsuccessfully, and I am in no hurry to try again.

Comment: @JonSpring Using `import::from` inside a package is a bad idea because it uses the global scope (unless you explicitly specify `.into`); and using the (superior) `import::into` doesn’t really have any advantage over using `NAMESPACE` directives.

Comment: @Peter Thank you! (Also to all the other contributors). I am sorry I forgot to offer you to post your comment as an answer. If you do I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
Try using patchwork::wrap_plots(plot1, plot2, plot3, ncol = 1). 
See documentation for formatting plot layout. 

library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
plot2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear)) + geom_bar()
plot3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp)) + geom_histogram(bins = 10)

wrap_plots(plot1, plot2, plot3, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>